# Unity создание сборного юнита

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр, model, unity3d-android

Делаю игру на Unity, пытаюсь сделать собираемый танчик из разных деталей, но незнаю как правильно реализовать.
Должно получится вот это.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Детали представлены в префабах

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочу соединить их в коде с помощью джоинтов, а не простым вложением в иерирархию, так как мне нужно чтобы компонент, отвечающий за управление, придавал силу не ко всему танку в целом, а только к шасси.
И проблема заключается в том что будет много всяких разных частей танка разных размеров, а необходимо чтобы они все друг к другу присоединялись правильно.
Попытался написать компонент, с помощью которого можно было бы определять точки присоединения для каждой детали, но мне кажется существует решение получше, помогите мне его найти.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: дело в том, что у корпуса и шасси нулевая координата находится в их середине, то при совмещении  получится так, что шасси окажется внутри корпуса, а оно должно прилегать к днищу корпуса

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создавай пустой `GameObject`, прикрепи модель `Hull` и скрипт (не к модели, а go) `hullPoints` с 2мя `public` полями: TowerPoint, ChassisPoint куда прикрешиш 2 пустых `GameObject` расположенных, где нужно. Hull готов!

```
Hull (hullPoints с сылками на TowerPoint и ChassisPoint)
 - Hull (Модель)
 - TowerPoint
 - ChassisPoint
```

Создавай пустой `GameObject`, прикрепи модель `Tower0`, приподними так, чтобы основание было в низу, а не в центре модельки и крепилось к `TowerPoint`. Скрипт `towerPoints` с полем `GunPoint` и `GameObject` откуда будет торчать ствол.

```
Tower (towerPoints с сылкой на GunPoint)
 - Tower0 (Модель)
 - GunPoint
```

и т.д. По сути детали готовятся без какой либо логики в скриптах, только ссылки на позиции.

Comment: Чисто с точки зрения оптимизации лучше использовать Vector3 и кастомный редактор. Создавать отдельные `go` для таких вещей - оверкилл :)

Comment: Аааа... так ты хочешь рассказать ему, как писать кастумный редактор и что это... удачи... оптимизируй =D

Comment: Так ответ хороший, я ничего не говорю, но тут база знаний, я же не только для автора топика это написал)